# Missing text in Windows dialog boxes

Tags: windows-server-2003

After an update was installed via automatic updates dialog boxes have lost some of their text including some tabs.  Example: http://rs-us.net/dialogbox.JPG

Comment: I recall this happening to a package that was developed in-house at my last place of employment. I don't recall all the details but the problem was traced to a font, so if you get no better answers that may be a line to search on.

Comment: I went ahead and replaced the default system fonts with another server's fonts and unfortunately it had no effect on the issue.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Have you rebooted the server?

Answer (score 0):

Which update was it?  Does the problem persist if you uninstall the update via the add/remove programs control panel?

Comment: I wish I knew which update caused the issue.  The problem is that when automatic updates install it's usually multiple updates installed at a time.  Being a production server it's not possible to start removing one after another until I find it either.

Comment: My question is why you would have automatic updates updating servers unbeknownst to you? You don't know what updates were applied and when? That's a sure fire recipe for problems IMHO. No offense intended.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not see this on a server,  I did have this issue on Win98 with one particular application. Like John said it was a font issue.  Since you say you've replaced the fonts with the fonts from another server,  I'm guessing you copied the actual font files (TTFs) over.  Maybe its not the font, but the linkage that is broken.  Have you tried changing the font used in the dialog boxes?    Also is there any chance the font color is set to gray?